# Compatible with PluginInterface::setController(Zend\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface $controller)

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm working php and zend framework 2.3.9.  I needed a view helper (FileQuery) to call a plugin (FileQueryPlugin) which calls a database query.  Dependency injection was recommended to me.

Originally FilePluginQUery was implementing AbstractPluginManager.  However I was getting a 'No instance returned' error message, and the expanded error message recommended 'implements PluginInterface'.

From module.config.php

```
'view_helpers' => array(
    'invokables'=> array(
        'MenuBuildLink' => 'qatools\View\Helper\MenuBuildLink',
    ),
    'factories' => array(
        'FileQuery' => function ($container, $requestedName) {
            return new \qatools\View\Helper\FileQuery($container->getServiceLocator()->get(\Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager::class)->get('\qatools\Plugins\FileQueryPlugin'));
        },
    ),
),
'plugins' => array(
    'invokables'=> array(
        'FileQueryPlugin' => 'qatools\Plugins\FileQueryPlugin'
    ),
),
```

From FileQuery.php

class FileQuery extends AbstractHelper {

```
protected $fileQueryPlugin;

public function __construct(FileQueryPlugin $fileQueryPlugin)
{   
    $this->fileQueryPlugin = $fileQueryPlugin;

    return $fileQueryPlugin;
}

public function getModifiedBy($filename) 
{
    return $this->fileQueryPlugin->getModifiedBy($filename);
}
```

}

From FileQueryPlugin.php

class FileQueryPlugin implements PluginInterface {

```
public function getModifiedBy($filename) {
    $fileQuery = $this->getServiceLocator->get('qatools\Model\GroupFilesTable');
    $modified = $fileQuery->getModifiedBy($filename);

    return $modified;
}

public function validatePlugin($plugin) {

}

public function setController(Dispatchable $controller) {

}

public function getController() {

}
```

}

Here is the full error message.

[25-Aug-2019 20:16:00 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of qatools\Plugins\FileQueryPlugin::setController(qatools\Plugins\Dispatchable $controller) must be compatible with Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\PluginInterface::setController(Zend\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface $controller) in /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/module/qatools/src/qatools/Plugins/FileQueryPlugin.php on line 10

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add a use statement.  Once I added it that error went away.

use Zend\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface as Dispatchable;